# What is 0 - (-128) with 2's complement notationequal to?

Tags: c, binary, bit

I am struggling to understand if there is any overflow with the following equation using 8 bit signed integers.

0b00000000 - 0b10000000

Comment: This would be better expressed as code, not something that's one degree removed from code. Also compile with all warnings (`-Wall`) to see if the compiler is hesitant to deal with that code.

Comment: Yes, this question definitely needs example code.

Comment: `0b10000000` is not really "2's complement notation".  It is a _binary_ notation of an 8-bit value.  `0b...0,1 digits...` is a non-standard _integer binary constant_, usually of type `int`.  C code cannot do a subtraction using 8 bit math, even if the constants are `char`  as [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595555/2410359) well explains.  If the answer/comments to not well address your question, you really should add more detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question is tagged `c`, and in C, all arithmetic in types lower-rank than `int` gets promoted to `int`, and `int` has at least 16-bit range, so `(signed char)0-((signed char)-128)` is just 128.